# utf-8 special characters not displaying

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8

I moved my website from my local test server to NameCheap shared hosting and now I'm running into a problem - some of the pages aren't displaying utf-8 special characters properly (showing question marks instead). All pages are utf-8 encoded, as are all database tables. The strange thing is, some pages display correctly and some don't, in a seemingly random pattern.

For instance, my index page is fine, but my profile page isn't. faq.html works fine, but when I rename it to faq.php it doesn't. And weirdest of all, I have a page with two JQuery tabs where one displays correctly and the other doesn't!

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: have you checked the encoding with Developer Tools? (F12 in most browsers)

Comment: Yes, it says it's utf-8 for all pages.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is really annoying problem to fix but you can try these.

First of all, make sure the file is actually saved in UTF-8 format.

Then check that you have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` in your HTML header.

You can also try calling `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the beginning of your PHP script or adding `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to your .htaccess file.

Comment: I have the meta tag that specifies charset=utf-8 in my header. Adding AddDeafultCHarset UTF-8 to my .htaccess doesn't help. I'd rather avoid solution directly from PHP code as it's a pretty complex site.

Comment: My problem has usually been that the actual files were not in UTF-8 format. For example the character `ä` of ASCII will show as `�` if the browser reads it as UTF-8 but the actual file isn't.

Comment: The actual files are definitely utf-8, and they worked perfectly on my EasyPHP.

Comment: GREAT!!! This worked for me (I'm using WordPress.... stupid WordPress!!!): AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I had php set to utf-8 everywhere, like you all said. But, as @RCE said, the files were not in UTF-8. I converted all of them using Notepad++, saving them as UTF-8. The accented chars where then converted to squares and, when running the site, the squares became the question mark inside the diamond.. I had to manually review each accent in each static page in order to assure the portuguese characteres (ç, á, ã, é, à, etc) are ok after the change.

Comment: If using PHP, may also need utf8_encode(...)

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like that if you request `faq.html` the webserver signals your browser that the file is in UTF-8 encoding.

Check that with your browser which encoding is announced and used, please see the documentation of your browser how to do that. Every browser has this, most often accessible via the menu (to specify your preference which website's encoding should be used) and to see what the server returned, you often find this in page properties.

Then it sounds like that if you request `faq.php` the webserver singals your browser that the file is in some other encoding. Probably no charset/encoding is given as per default PHP configuration setting. As it's a PHP file you can most often solve this by changing the PHP configuration [`default_charset`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) directive:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

Locate your php.ini on the host and edit it accordingly.

If you don't have the php.ini available, you can change this by code as well by using the [`ini_set`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/ini_set) function:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Take care that you change this very early in your script because PHP needs to be able to send out headers to have this working, and headers can't be set any longer if they have already been send.

Manually sending the `Content-Type` header-line does work, too:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Additionally it's good practice that all the HTML pages you output have this header as well in their HTML `<head>` section:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    ...
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have php.ini available. 

The browser says the encoding is utf-8, and it displays the same in all browsers.

I have the proper encoding declared in my header. I've tried adding it to .htaccess anyway but that did nothing. Do you think it could be a problem with the hosting account somehow?

Comment: Using ini_set displays the characters but it doesn't read any PHP content then!

Comment: If the browser reports UTF-8 and it does not properly display, your data is broken somewhere. Encoding is like a chain, if one element is wrong, the end result is wrong. Take care and locate the element of the chain that is not working. And what do you mean by "any PHP content then"?

Comment: I have a PHP header included (just a banner with some links). When I use the ini_set function, the page doesn't show the header - it acts like I'd renamed it to .html.

The files displayed properly on my EasyPHP, how could they have gotten broken by being uploaded to a hosting account?

Answer (score 4):

set meta tag in head as

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

use the link http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html to replace the symbols character you want.

then use str_replace like

```
    $find = array('â€œ', 'â€™', 'â€¦', 'â€”', 'â€“', 'â€˜', 'Ã©', 'Â', 'â€¢', 'Ëœ', 'â€'); // en dash
                        $replace = array('“', '’', '…', '—', '–', '‘', 'é', '', '•', '˜', '”');
$content = str_replace($find, $replace, $content);
```

Its the method i use and help alot. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PHP and none of the above worked (as it was my case), you need to set the locale with utf-8 encoding.

Like this

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_CA.utf-8');
```

Answer (score 4):

I solve my issue by using utf8_encode();

> $str = "kamé";
>
> echo utf8_encode($str);

Hope this help someone.

Comment: exactly what I needed, thanks.
Used in Laravel, PHP

Answer (score 0):

If all the other answers didn't work for you, try **disabling HTTP input encoding translation**.

This is a setting related to PHP extension **mbstring**.
This was the problem in my case. This setting was enabled by default in my server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your file are not with the same encoding. 
First run the following command in all your files:

```
file -i filename.*
```

In order to fix the problem you have to change all your files to uft-8. You can do it with the command iconv:

```
iconv -f fromcode -t tocode filename > newfilename
```

Example:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 index.html > fixed/index.html
```

After this you can run file -i fixedx/index.html and you will see that your file is now in uft-8

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line in the head tag fixed my issue.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above work, it could be the mysqli connection encoding.

In my case, the php file (whatever.php) was UTF-8, the html was declared as UTF-8, and the database was even in UTF-8, yet the characters were still not showing up correctly.

Apparently, mysqli decided to default to a different encoding.

So I added

`$conn->set_charset("utf8");`

after

`$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

and it worked.

If your database tables are `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and not `utf8_general_ci`, then put this instead:

`$conn->set_charset("utf8mb4");`

Go into phpmyadmin (or your preferred database manager) and check which encoding your tables are in to select the correct encoding.

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php