# ù,é it turns in to �

Tags: html

I have a french website, the below is my header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

I am trying to put these charactors ù,é  it turns in to �

Please tell me why?

Thank you.

Comment: Where does your data come from?

Comment: a php file, but its written in the file not db

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356187/utf-8-special-characters-not-displaying

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to put these charactors ù,é it turns in to �

That is a pretty certain indicator that the text you output is not UTF-8 encoded as you say in the header. My guess would be it's ISO-8859-1 encoded.

This can be because

- The HTML file you are editing isn't UTF-8 encoded. Save it as UTF-8 -  the option for that is often in the "Save As..." dialog of your editor or IDE.
- The database connection you are getting the text from isn't UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the html file as UTF-8 format. Also you can add an attribute lang="fr" to your html tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in head section

```
<meta http-equiv="encoding" content="text/html" />
```

I think it will works for you.