# Special characters not showing up Correctly in TEXTBOX

Tags: php, html, sql, utf-8, smarty

I am using PHP + HTML + smarty (as a template).

There is some dynamic content coming from user's input.

When user enters some special characters for example `—.‘@•` it's been saved properly in variable.

But when I try to show that same content of special character in `textbox` (using smarty template) it shows something like this: `�.�@�`

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> is already included in the`Header`.

I already referred this: [utf-8 special characters not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356187/utf-8-special-characters-not-displaying)

None of its solution worked for me.

Comment: Are you doing something with the variable like passing it through another function?

Comment: @Augwa: its MVC structure, so am passing the variable from Controller to View(a template) and showing it in `textbox`. When I echo that variable with special characters in a Controller(.php file) its shows up correctly. But when I try to display same thing in smarty-template its shows those wired characters.

Comment: it's quite possible that the function that it's going through converts it to ascii, as such all utf-8 characters are lost. Without more information I don't really have more insight on this, other than you will need to look at the execution chain from where the data gets processed by the smarty template.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that everything that deals with the string supports UTF-8. Mainly:

- If you store the string in a table before displaying it, check that it is UTF-8 encoded (eg. for MySQL, have `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` when you create the table).
- Make sure that the view files are saved as UTF-8. In your text editor, you can normally choose the encoding. Or choose "Save as..." and choose the encoding there.
- I'm not familiar with Smarty but make sure it's not converting the string to some non-UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Yes, the db table structure have `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`. I am using MVC structure, so problem seems when I pass the variable to `View` via `Controller`. Because when I echo that variable with special characters in a Controller(.php file) its shows up correctly but not the template file.

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 lines right after $dbconn:

$dbconn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$pass,$database) or die("no db connection!");

mysqli_query($dbconn, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS =latin1;");
mysqli_query($dbconn, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT =latin1;");

That will draw data from the MySQL as is, don't encode it.

Good luck!
M

Comment: Why use Latin1 on a utf-8 table?